# Build <key,value> map using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I've 2 tables: `TA(id (fkB), key, value)` and `TB(id, ...)`. I was to build a map in `class B`, with `<Key,Value>` from `TA`. In `SQL`, I would say, `select Key`, value from A, B where `A.id  = B.id` and `B.id = <id>`. How to get this in Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

As you have not added entities properly so I will use some dummy Entity

Lets say you have 2 entity

User and Section

your query will be like this

```
select u.firstName, u.lastName from User u , Section s where u.id = s.id;
```